# What do I do with the Curse of the Rougarou and Monstrous Transformation cards at setup?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

Setup says to set aside the following cards: Lady Esprit, Bear Trap, and Fishing Net, which usually means to hold off on them as they will come into play later.  However, there is no mention of the Curse of the Rougarou card or the Monstrous Transformation card.  Why would they not include these two cards as cards to be set aside?  Are they to **not** be set aside and somehow put into the setup more actively at the outset?

Comment: Could you please create a tag wiki for Curse of the Rougarou? Otherwise, it will be purged in a few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer: set them aside, and don't worry about them. The slightly spoiler filled answer....

**Curse of the Rougarou**

> This card will come into play during the scenario (specifically after completing the first act). It should have been included in the set aside instructions.

**Monstrous Transformation**

> This card only becomes available during a particular resolution after the scenario is complete (so only applicable if you are playing the scenario as part of a campaign).